# Programming a "t command" into a serial object

Tags: serial-port

So I have a grouping of "t commands", which is a string.  These commands are supposed to be sent to a serial port, which will then run the command.  I am using something similar to this in order to change the string into byte form which can then be read by the serial port:
(I'm using pySerial)

```
import serial
s=serial.Serial('COM')
str=('t command')
str=bytearray(str,"utf-8")
s.write.(str)
```

there are no errors, but the command is not working.  Anybody have any ideas?